# NVIDIA CUDA SDK Examples Compilation Unsupported Architecture 'compute_20'

Tags: compilation, cuda, nvidia, compiler-errors, gpu

On compilation of the CUDA SDK, I'm getting a nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_20' My toolkit is 2.3 and on a shared system (i.e cant really upgrade) and the driver version is also 2.3, running on 4 Tesla C1060s

If it helps, the problem is being called in radixsort.

It appears that a few people online have had this problem but i havent found anywhere that actually gives a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe compute_20 is targeting Fermi hardware, which you do not have.  Also, Cuda 2.3 doesn't support Fermi features or compute_20.  Try using compute_13 instead.

Comment: Cant believe i missed that! forgive the stupid question; how do i set it to compile against compute_13?

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling the 3.x SDK with a 2.3 Toolkit, that won't work since as you've now seen compute_20 is not supported.

The simplest solution is to either upgrade your Toolkit or downgrade your SDK. You could try changing the makefile (common.mk in C/common) on Linux or changing the Build Properties on Windows to select only compute_13, but there may be other problems so it may be simpler to align the SDK/Toolkit versions.

Note that if you don't have administrator priviledges then you can install a local version of the Toolkit alongside the SDK but you would need admi to upgrade the driver.