# cudaErrorNoDevice GTS250 gentoo

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gentoo

**first question is**
cudaGetDeviceCount return **cudaErrorNoDevice**:
 *This indicates that no CUDA-capable devices were detected by the installed CUDA driver.*

`cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version`

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  260.19.26  Sun Nov 28 22:38:24 PST 2010
GCC version:  gcc version 4.4.5 (Gentoo 4.4.5 p1.2, pie-0.4.5)
```

`lspci -v`

```
...
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G92 [GeForce GTS 250] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at fb000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f8000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at ec00 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fafe0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel <?>
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia
 ...
```

`nvcc -V`

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2010 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Nov__3_16:14:08_PDT_2010
Cuda compilation tools, release 3.2, V0.2.1221
```

CUDA computing SDK 3.2.16

and when i try to make sdk samples i get **second problem**:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/style/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/src/MersenneTwister'
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_20'
```

[i've tried to edit common.mk, but i don't know what exactly i should edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047909/nvidia-cuda-sdk-examples-compilation-nsupported-architecture-compute-20)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Verify if you have a /dev/nvidia0. If you do not, you may need to restart your X.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the error where it says you have no CUDA devices.

In answer to your second question:

GeForce GTS 250 supports CUDA 1.1 not 2.0. You need to edit the compilation flags to replace compute_20 with compute_11.

Comment: You said you didn't know what to edit. We're going to need more information in order to help. It's unlikely you'll find someone with an identical setup who can reproduce this, so you're going to need to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

As I had the same problem, the only solution that worked for me was to reinstall the driver. Notice that the driver is not included in the SDK.